# Approximately what percentage of the mutual fund industry have high water mark clauses?

Tags: mutual-funds

While common in hedge funds, high water marks appear to be less common in mutual funds. But I'm not entirely sure about that. I've encountered a few mutual fund product contracts that make use of a HWM, but have not found any consolidated information source to see how prevalent this is in product design industry wide.

### Question

What is (or where might I find data on) the approximate proportion of  mutual funds that have HWMs to the industry total count of mutual funds?

For reference, here is one mutual fund with a performance fee and HWM:

[image]

Comment: Ideally I'd like to put a number to this, but if that's not feasible I may consider a qualitative answer like "virtually none," "very little," "about half" or "very common."

Comment: "I've encountered a few mutual fund product contracts that make use of a HWM" -- if you could cite those, it would give a better idea of what you're asking about. Unlike hedge fund fees, mutual fund fees are typically a flat percentage of assets (expense ratio) not directly tied to performance. So HWM doesn't even seem to make sense (it is intended to avoid paying performance-based fees for gains that are only recouping previous losses).

Comment: As far as I know, management fees (expense ratio) arithmetic isn't different between the industries: both are based on assets under management. It's just that hedge funds tend to be upwards of 200bps or more whereas mutual funds are around 50bps (depending if active/passive and/or underlyings).  However, fee-adjusted returns, while often buried in the prospectus or marketing material, still matter in theory as mutual fund investors can pay for performance twice. But again the extent will hinge on how many mutual funds have things like HWMs.

Comment: But the HWM feature, at least as defined [here](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/h/highwatermark.asp), refers specifically to *performance fees* (e.g., 20% of profits, not 2% of assets). And mutual funds typically don't have performance fees.

Comment: @nanoman Oh, I see what you mean. Yeah, HWM for performance fees not management fees. There are some mutual funds that do have those though, included an example.